# How to return first loop different from the rest of the loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var item1 = function() {
    var item1 = 'ITEM1 HERE';
    var item2 = 'THE REST HERE';

    if what_to_put_here() {
        return item1;
    } else if what_to_put_here {
        return item2;
    }
};
```

item1 = the first loop will have complete contents

item2 = from 2nd and the rest of the loop will have partial contents

Hi, I have a loop and I want the first loop to be different from the rest of the loop. I am still learning javascript by myself. Though google is there but I do not know the term/words to use.
My questions, Is the code above is the right format? What are the functions to be used? Pls help. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `boolean` to trap the first iterate

like this.

```
var isFirstloop = true;
```

inside your loop. it should look like this

```
if(isFirstloop){
   isFirstloop = false;
   //ITEM 1 HERE
}else{
  //THE REST HERE
}
```